# Circles keep accumulating and are not merging correctly

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to merge these circles but I keep getting a graph of accumulating circles as opposed to circles moving across the graph?

What am I missing?

I have attached the code below. This function is called updatechart. It corresponds to a slider. So whenever I move the slider across the screen. I corresponding year it lands on is where the updated circle data should move.

```
var filteredyears = d3.nest()
     .key(function(d) {
       if(year === d.year){
         return d;
     }
   }).entries(globaldataset);


var circled = svg.selectAll('.countries')
 .data(filteredyears[1].values);

var circledEnter = circled.enter()

circled.merge(circledEnter);

circledEnter.append("circle").attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.gdpPercap);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.lifeExp);
    })
    .attr('transform', "translate("+[40,30]+")")
    .attr( 'r', function(d) {
      return rScale(d.population) / 100})
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      if(d.continent == 'Asia'){
        return '#fc5a74';
      } else if (d.continent == 'Europe') {
        return '#fee633';
      } else if (d.continent == 'Africa') {
        return '#24d5e8';
      } else if (d.continent == 'Americas') {
        return '#82e92d';
      } else if (d.continent == 'Oceania') {
        return '#fc5a74';
      }
    })
    .style("stroke", "black");
  circled.exit().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of issues using the `merge()` method, which is indeed quite hard to understand initially.

First, you have to reassign your selection:

```
circled = circled.merge(circledEnter);
```

Now, from this point on, apply the changes to `circled`, not to `circledEnter`:

```
circled.attr("//etc...
```

Besides that, your `exit` selection won't work, since you're calling it on the merged selection. Put it before the `merge`.

Finally, `append` goes to the `circledEnter` selection, before merging, as well as all attributes that don't change.

Here is a very basic demo showing it:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

render();

function render() {
  var data = d3.range(~~(1 + Math.random() * 9));
  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data);
  circles.exit().remove();
  var circlesEnter = circles.enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d);
    });
  circles = circlesEnter.merge(circles);
  circles.attr("cx", function() {
      return 5 + Math.random() * 290
    })
    .attr("cy", function() {
      return 5 + Math.random() * 140
    });
}

d3.interval(render, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```